# Chai assertion includes or for string

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to traverse through a list of elements and want to assert that the body includes either of the 2 values.
I am trying to use the following but it only lets me assert one value.

```
expect(cellText).includes(toDateFormat);
```

How can I make an assertion that allows me to assert multiple values having OR condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Chai's satisfy](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_satisfy) to accomplish this.

> Invokes the given matcher function with the target being passed as the first argument, and asserts that the value returned is truthy.

```js
expect(cellText).to.satisfy(function(text) {
  return text.includes(toDateFormat) || text.includes(otherFormatVariable);
})
```

If you have a long list of potential expected values, you could simplify this by having those values in an array, and using `array.filter()` to find instances of the actual text value in the expected text value, and returning the length of the filtered array.

```js
const expected = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
expect(cellText).to.satisfy(function(text) {
  return expected.filter((x) => cellText.includes(x)).length
});
```

Comment: This looks good. Also any way we can perform the same if we have a list of string values and want to do similar assertion?

Comment: Is the list of string values the actual values or the expected values?

Comment: The list is the expected values. Basically, I want to check if cellText equals any of the values in the list

Comment: Added a potential solution using array.filter. maybe not the best, but I think it'll get the job done

Answer (score 6):

A simple way is to use [oneOf](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_oneof) assertion

> Asserts that the target is a member of the given array list.

```js
expect(cellText).to.be.oneOf([format1, format2])
```

or for partial formats

```js
expect(cellText).to.contain.oneOf([format1, format2])
```